# Getting Too many soql while running the test class

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

After adding my below code when I run test class on the whole trigger it is giving too many soql:101 error on some other lines. After removing the code it works fine. I am unable to figure out what is wrong with below code.

```
 If(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate){
        //RecordType rt = [select Id from RecordType where Name = 'Parent Child' and SobjectType = 'Case' limit 1];
        Set<id> ParentCases = new set<id>();
        List<case> CasetoUpdate = new List<Case>();
        for(case caseObj : Trigger.new){
                if((CaseObj.Status!=Trigger.oldMap.get(caseObj.id).status || caseObj.OwnerId!=Trigger.oldMap.get(CaseObj.id).ownerId)){
                    ParentCases.add(caseObj.Id);
                }
            system.debug('parentcases list -----------'+Parentcases);               
        }      

       if(!ParentCases.isEmpty()){
        //List<case> ChildCase = new List<case>([select id, RepeatedCase__c,Repeated_Case_owner__c, Repeated_Status__c, RepeatedCase__r.status, RepeatedCase__r.owner.name from case where RepeatedCase__c IN : Trigger.new AND RepeatedCase__c!=null AND Repeated_case_owner__c!=NULL AND Repeated_status__c!=NULL]);
            for(case CaseObj1 : [select id, RepeatedCase__c,Repeated_Case_owner__c, Repeated_Status__c, RepeatedCase__r.status, RepeatedCase__r.owner.name from case where RepeatedCase__c IN : Trigger.new AND RepeatedCase__c!=null AND Repeated_case_owner__c!=NULL AND Repeated_status__c!=NULL]){
                caseObj1.Repeated_Case_Owner__c = caseObj1.RepeatedCase__r.Owner.name;
                caseObj1.Repeated_Status__c = caseObj1.RepeatedCase__r.status;
                caseToupdate.add(caseObj1);
            }
        }
      update caseToUpdate;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

We had other utility class which had a boolean variable of parent case being  open or closed.
Checked the boolean variable and it worked.

```
If(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate){
    //RecordType rt = [select Id from RecordType where Name = 'Parent Child' and SobjectType = 'Case' limit 1];
    Set<id> ParentCases = new set<id>();
    List<case> CasetoUpdate = new List<Case>();
    for(case caseObj : Trigger.new){
            if((CaseObj.Status!=Trigger.oldMap.get(caseObj.id).status || caseObj.OwnerId!=Trigger.oldMap.get(CaseObj.id).ownerId)){
                ParentCases.add(caseObj.Id);
            }
        system.debug('parentcases list -----------'+Parentcases);               
    }      

   if(!ParentCases.isEmpty()){
    //List<case> ChildCase = new List<case>([select id, RepeatedCase__c,Repeated_Case_owner__c, Repeated_Status__c, RepeatedCase__r.status, RepeatedCase__r.owner.name from case where RepeatedCase__c IN : Trigger.new AND RepeatedCase__c!=null AND Repeated_case_owner__c!=NULL AND Repeated_status__c!=NULL]);
        for(case CaseObj1 : [select id, RepeatedCase__c,Repeated_Case_owner__c, Repeated_Status__c, RepeatedCase__r.status, RepeatedCase__r.owner.name from case where RepeatedCase__c IN : Trigger.new AND RepeatedCase__c!=null AND Repeated_case_owner__c!=NULL AND Repeated_status__c!=NULL]){
            caseObj1.Repeated_Case_Owner__c = caseObj1.RepeatedCase__r.Owner.name;
            caseObj1.Repeated_Status__c = caseObj1.RepeatedCase__r.status;
            caseToupdate.add(caseObj1);
        }
    }
  update caseToUpdate;
 }
```